# Loging into firebase with a codeanywhere HTML5 connection/devbox

Tags: html, firebase, npm, firebase-tools, codeanywhere

I installed firebase on a codeanywhere html5 connection. When I attempted to run the shell command >`firebase login`, the response gave me a URL to launch in order to log in. After logging in and allowing the permissions, it redirected to a localhost URL with this error:

```
This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect.
Search Google for localhost 9005
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

What is the appropriate way to login when using firebase from within a codeanywhere box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since Codeanywhere is not a local environment, you will need to append `--no-localhost` to the firebase login command:

```
$ firebase login --no-localhost
```

This will generate the usual login URL, but upon completion, you will be given an authorization token to paste into the CLI.

Further instructions here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools